# Webpack output path of config file

Tags: webpack

I want to output path to webpack config file inside webpack.

I am importing path module: `var path = require("path");` but there is no method to output current dir path and i can't find documentation for this specific webpack module/import.

Comment: Can you elobrate bit more

Comment: I need to get path to webpack.config.js file inside that config file. I want to echo something like "~/projectDir/" inside webpack.

Comment: try this `__dirname` or `process.cwd()`

Comment: @MladenPetrovic did you make any progress on this? I'm trying to echo a log from the webpack config file but with no success yet.

Comment: Yes, checkout my answer i just added.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you can get location of webpack with [context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html)

So i am using it like this:
`module.exports = [ context: __dirname ]`

Paths can be joined like this: 
`path.join(__dirname, 'images/logo.png');`